# TCPDF - Is there a way to adjust single table row height?

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I am trying for two days now, with no result, to adjust a single rows min-height in a table, with no success.

I am using the following method to create my table:

```
<?php 
$html = <<<EOD
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Text 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Text 2
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
EOD;

$this->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
?>
```

I already tried setting td padding, td margin, td height, tr height, with no success. I tried these from CSS and HTML too. The only thing I managed to achieve, is to see a row's height larger then the original value, but I want to make it shorter. I tried searching in the documentation of TCPDF, but the only thing I found is that TCPDF is not supporting padding and margin. Do any of you know some kind of "hack" to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you're probably running into is the actual height of lines of text.  Internally, TCPDF uses the cell height ratio to control the rendered line height.  When you have a TD with a single line of text, the smallest you can make it is the line's total height.  So the minimum size of a `td` cell is `fontsize * cellheightratio + any cellpadding proscribed`

cellpadding can come from the `cellpadding` attribute, so I set it to 0 for this example.  I believe at least some of the padding dimensions can also be set with `setCellPaddings` before writing the HTML.

You can set the cell height ratio by using a `line-height` CSS declaration to make rows smaller. (You can also, of course, just reduce the font size as well.)

```
<?php

//For demonstration purposes, set line-height to be double the font size.
//You probably DON'T want to include this line unless you need really spaced
//out lines.
$this->setCellHeightRatio(2);

//Note that TCPDF will display whitespace from the beginning and ending
//of TD cells, at least as of version 5.9.206, so I removed it.
$html = <<<EOD
<table style="border:1px solid black;" border="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="line-height: 100%;">
    <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="line-height: 80%;">
    <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="line-height: 50%;">
    <td>Row 4, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 4, Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
EOD;

$this->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
```

The above code on my 5.9.206 installation produces this:
[image: Visual example of set line-heights.]

This works out to row 1 being big, twice the font size.  Row 2 sets the line-height to be 100% of the font size. Row 3 is 80%.  Row 4 there is 50%.

*Note that if your text wraps, it'll look terrible at very reduced line-heights.

Comment: This is correct. And it applies to empty table cells as well.

Comment: I ran into this as well except I was not using HTML cells, just the standard Cell method. I needed an exact height to get page breaking borders to work correctly and I spent hours scratching my head not knowing FontSize was changing my sizes, throwing off the breaks.  Saving my original font size, then calling SetFontSize(0) before writing the Cell with a Ln(), then resetting font size back fixed it. Thanks for this!

Comment: how to add multiple $this->setCellHeightRatio(2); ?

Comment: Working Awsome. Thanks